# How do I keep by backend secure from third party clients

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth, ionic-framework

I want to use Ionic to connect with a Laravel rest API. As far as I know I should use OAuth to authenticate the user. How does this stop other clients/requests from accessing my rest API?

For instance if someone created another Ionic app or anything and requested a OAuth token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's still no way to perfectly protect your API source. As you mentioned, OAuth is one way to help protection.

I often use JWT, aka. [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/) with token-refresh which expires right after one use. You can check out my short tutorial on using J[WT with Laravel and AngularJS](https://medium.com/@petehouston/develop-a-simple-api-authentication-service-with-json-web-token-using-laravel-angularjs-and-240135855ef1#.mgkxanmu8), which is absolutely same with Ionic.

Comment: Thanks Pete, that's a good way. I really wouldn't want anyone to be able to access the rest api tho. I'm sure there's something there tho.